# Consuming API with User and Pass in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wordpress, api

I have an API coming from Wordpress -it uses a username and password. This was previously built in a system i'm working on. The api calls are being made from the front end so the credentials are hard coded and can be seen in the code and chrome dev tools. 
It is not a good idea to expose this, so i want to move it to the code behind.  Whats the best way to address this? Move the whole call to the back end? Create an end point? Use sessions?

I've seen many ideas but i want the simplest that doesn't require as much re working of the ajax call. I've been reading many solutions but they seem like reworking that portion of the application.

```
function authApi() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxxxxxxx/token',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $.param({ username: 'user', password: 'nnnnnnnnnnnn' }) 
    })
```

Comment: Moving everything regarding authentication to the backend is best. You can also implement a facade web service for interacting with the protected API that your Wordpress application doesn't need to manage tokens.

Comment: Move to the backend AND use sessions. Is the application distributed to customer, or internal only? If the former you don't want it to be hard-coded on the backend either, because decompilers exist.

Comment: its a web application so its not distributed but its for customers. Thanks, i'll move it to back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a WebMethod in web forms:

```
       [WebMethod]
        public async Task<string> AuthenticateApi()
        {            
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString(),
                password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString()
            });

            string contents;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response =  await client.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"].ToString(),  
new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

           return contents;
        }
```

Or you can also use HttpPost in MVC:

```
            [HttpPost]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            public async Task<string>  AuthenticateApi()
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    username =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString(),
                    password =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString()
                });

                var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"].ToString();

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                    var contents = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return contents;
                }
            }
```

Then call in Javascript like so:

```
function authApi() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '../AuthenticateApi',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('AuthorizationData', JSON.stringify(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication: is to identifying a user. It can be OAuth or user/password or you can use service such as Firebase Auth.

Protect your API you can use API Gateway to only allow request from some domain, rate-limit, restrict only from some IP. Again I'm a fan of Google, you can research Cloud Endpoints, or you can use Kong, a good alternative.